# How do I use arrows here?

Tags: haskell, arrows

Consider

```
foldr (\x (a,b) -> (a || x==2, b || x==7 )) (False,False) [1..6]
--(True,False)
```

Ignoring the fact that this could be written easily using `elem`, I have the strong feeling that I could employ `Arrow` syntax to simplify the lambda, I just can't get it right.

Can this lambda be simplified using arrows? And do you have any general hints concerning how to "see" when arrows might work, and how to find the right expression?

Comment: Edward Kmett liberated me from my need to care about arrows three weeks ago [with these comments on Brandon Simmons's blog](http://brandon.si/code/categories-that-want-to-be-arrows/#comment-437318026).

Comment: @DanielLyons nevertheless, the typical arrow combinators `&&&`, `|||` and `***` can be useful because of the function instance of arrow.

Comment: Agreed. I just don't think the payoff for truly, fully understanding them justifies the pain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pull the computation out of the foldr -

```
ghci> :m +Control.Arrow
ghci> any (==2) &&& any (==7) $ [1..6]
(True,False)
```

But if you want to be sure you're only traversing the list once, try using the [bifunctor package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors):

```
ghci> :m +Data.Bifunctor +Data.Bifunctor.Apply
ghci> foldr (bilift2 (||) (||) . ((==2) &&& (==7))) (False, False) [1..6]
(True,False)
```

Comment: Or shorter: `elem 2 &&& elem 7 $ [1..6]`

Answer (score 6):

```
foldr (\x -> (|| x==2) *** (|| x==7)) (False,False) [1..6]
```

I don't think you can abstract the `x` out with arrows.

Edit: well, seems like you can:

```
foldr (uncurry (***) . (((||) . (==2)) &&& ((||) . (==7)))) (False,False) [1..6]
```

Comment: Is `(||)` an empty expression surrounded by banana brackets? ;-)

Comment: If disambiguation is indeed necessary, you can always give it more whitespace: `( || )`. But using 6 characters to refer to a 2-character  operator is atrocious.

Comment: Even if the solution doesn't look very cute, I'll keep the `uncurry (***)` trick in mind. Thanks!